# what is equivalent of a windows service on azure?

Tags: azure

what is the way to have an always running process on azure? on windows it is windows service, but do i have to get a virtual machine just to have a single running process? I have looked at various compute options but none of them seems to match what a windows service does. Is there a different way to achieve what a windows service does on azure?

Comment: It depends a lot on what the service is doing on what you should do. For example an image processing background service would be different to a virus scanner background service. What does it do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should look at continuously-running web jobs. 
See [Running Background tasks with WebJobs on Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateContinuous).

Other choices are PaaS cloud services worker roles and Azure Service Fabric reliable services - but these are likely overkill if you just want a basic service.

Comment: After looking into what a web job actually is, I'd have to contest your suggestion. Wouldn't you agree that a worker role is far more suitable for the migration of a Windows service?

Comment: Worker Roles are what you want to run for Windows Services if you are going the Cloud Service route. 

Web Roles would be used for IIS instances to run Web API's or websites

Comment: Are they deprecating cloud services? I see that its only available via Classic (not RM).

Answer (score 41):

There is no specific way to run your code in Azure. You have lots of choices, and which you choose is really up to you (and a matter of opinion). But, objectively speaking:

- Install your service as you always have, in a Windows Server VM
- Run your code, without the Windows Service wrapper, in a VM (either Windows or Linux, depending on language)
- Pull your core code out of the service, and run it within a web/worker role (cloud service).
- Run your code in a WebJob.
- Run your code in a Web App (you'd need to add some way to get to it, like a REST API sitting in front of it)

I see that @Neil suggested Service Fabric in his answer. That works too, except you'll need to learn about Service Fabric in general, since it works a bit differently.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, loads of ways to skin this cat

Answer (score 5):

Azure function is a good candidate for migrating windows services into something cloud based. Azure function can be triggered by a timer and so like a windows service can be scheduled at a certain time of the day for example.
Please give read to my notes that I wrote while I worked on such a migration:
https://dumanhilltechnologies.com/blog/windows-service-migration-to-azure-function/

**An Update**
The above link is no more available, so please refer to Microsoft's documentation on timer-triggered Azure function here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Other options in .net core are to write a [BackgroundService](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-background-task-using-backgrounservice-class-in-asp-net-core/) and host it using Azure App Services or in a container instance using Azure Container Services.

Comment: I think I disagree on that. A windows service is running continuously, so replacing it via an Azure Function, which is, as you say, triggered at certain times, is not the best answer. Unless you trigger your function every single second. But that can lead to other issues. I see aan Azure Function more as a replacement on a Windows Scheduled Task in that case

Comment: Actually, I have used Azure Functions quite successfully like this.  It runs a Timer, so for example, every minute it fires off some code, just like a Windows Service or daemon would.  I have one such function in place for several years and have never had to touch it or check it, it juist works.

Comment: Link is broken!

Comment: Paul, if you're able to publish those notes somewhere that were on the now-expired blog and link to them that'd be really helpful.