# C# Console Application (game back-end): What's the easiest (but also scalable) way to host it?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I built a c# console application that's my game back-end.

I am considering using Azure, but not sure which Azure product is right for me since Azure App Service doesn't -by default- allows me to host a c# console application.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction because I got confused by the huge amount of similar products Azure provides.

Comment: What specifically does your "back end" do?  What is your budget? What is your expected customer base?

Comment: it's a game back-end, a c# socket server that enables real-time gaming experience, budget is not a problem, customers could be based anywhere @GeorgeStocker

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about finding hosting.

Comment: it does not, it's about ways to either find a solution to host this console app or a way to convert the console app to something else that can be deployed to Azure, @user2864740

Comment: @Mikethegreat The question is a bit off topic; but to give you a hand you could host it on a VM on Azure and that would get you running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this type of question is very broad (and off-topic, accordingly). Azure has dozens of services, each with specific features and advantages. Currently you're focused on App Services (Web Apps), and perhaps you could take advantage of that service, but you'd have a bit of work to do, integrating with it, since you have a console app currently. We really don't have any visibility into any code, and there's no specific question here (other than a general architecture one). A great discussion to have, for sure! But there's really no "right answer" for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host it on the cloud, it makes no sense it is a console appliction since you will not be logged on that server and watch the console output, unless you get an Azure Virtual Machine and host it there and then monitor it via RDP connection, but why would you do that...!

In general you can expose back end logic via WCF services hosted on IIS or also self hosted on Windows Services, and instead of console output you can then redirect taht output to either log files or database.

There should not be too much to rewrite and if your app is done well effort is limited to transition from console app to windows service or IIS WCF back end.

Also have a look here for some ideas on Azure service/backend offering: [what is equivalent of a windows service on azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36026424/559144)