# How to create .Net Core Azure WebJobs from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I am starting my first day with a few azure services.

I have a windows service and I want to create its equivalent cloud service, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026424/what-is-equivalent-of-a-windows-service-on-azure) question and have gone through the answers, and found out that WebJobs is a good choice.

So I decided to create a new project WebJobs project in visual studio (I have 2019 and 2022 both). But I can't find a template for .net core (.net 5 or 6). I can find only .net frameworks.

Then I saw read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#webjobs-as-net-core-console-apps) documentation, which mentions that I need to create a console app and follow the mentioned steps, so I this the only way to create .net core WebJobs using visual studio or am I missing something here?

I have also not found any resource when I searched by Webjobs in portal.azure.com. So how to create WebJobs from the Azure portal?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> how to create WebJobs from the Azure portal?

Firstly you need to create a web apps(App services) service as below:

[image]

Then in Left pane type webjobs you will find add to create a web job as below:

[image]

The file we upload here should come from Visual studio web job.(create a project with azure web job and import that in azure portal).

[image]

After giving all details you will get your web job created as below:

[image]

AFAIK, [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#webjobs-as-net-core-console-apps) is the way(you need to create console app) to do webjobs in Visual Studio and also refer [Doc1](https://code-maze.com/azure-webjobs-in-app-service/),[Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) for more information.

Comment: What if I selected .Net 6 as runtime while creating the app service? Can I upload WebJobs created in the .net framework ( as mentioned in the visual studio template). Which file do I need to upload?

Comment: You need to upload the file(web jobs created in .net frameowork in vs) which has same runtime as your web app service(you can check the runtime in configuration section of web app)

Comment: which particular file? Can you name it or its extension?

Comment: I have created a .net framework 4.8 webjob from visual studio. and created .net 6 application service. now tell me which file?

Comment: Go to bin/ release/(file) [Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-develop-and-deploy-azure-webjobs-in-azure-app-service/)

Comment: You can change the version of azure web app service to 4.8 and you can upload the file

Comment: but I want to create a .net core, not .net framework

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IP5w0Cy.png (Change the version here) The previous link i have given follow the process in .Net core(Given the reference for uploading the file)

Comment: again the same question. does it support app service in .net 6 and webjob in .net 4.8 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249473/discussion-between-rithwikbojja-and-vivek-nuna).